# Uploading Pictures via C# to ASP.NET MVC 3 Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on a Windows Phone 7 app. This app will empower people to upload pictures. My backend uses ASP.NET MVC 3. Right now, people can upload pictures. What I'm discovering though is that some of these pictures are not uploaded properly. Oddly, the picture is half uploaded, but the bottom half is purely gray.

I can't even think of a scenario where this would happen. Can somebody help me identify how this would even happen? Basically, a picture gets uploaded. The top half looks right. The bottom half is pure gray. It only happens occasionally. I have not been able to reproduce the problem myself. I only see that some of the photos that are being uploaded from my users have this.

Comment: Is this an internal app? If it's mobile-network, is the user's connection being dropped in the middle of the upload? Can you check the size before the upload and then check it at the end to validate success?

Answer (score 1):

This can occur if pictures are not fully uploaded, if, for example your user stops uploading in middle of the process.

By stopping, it can be a connectivity loss, application close, whatever.

You should check the upload is fully done before "validating" your data (IE check image file size against content-length of POST request).